# Form valid() ignore real string length

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

Got a strange issue.

I have a string in my model:

```
[StringLength(1000)]
public string Text { get; set; }
```

and it looks like this on view:

```
<td>@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Text)</td>
<td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Text)</td>
```

Also I have `$("#helpForm").valid()`, which supposed to prevent post form but here where issues start:

I am placing text with 999 length in TextArea. Seems fine because after adding 2 more char I got a exception, but after posting this, I receive 1023 length in model.

As I understand, each tabulation are counted as additional characher in textarea but, jquery not counting them and from here goes the difference. How I supposed to make jquery recognize tabulation as characher?

Comment: Hmmm interesting!!! , how about doing a custom validation with textarea inner html length check?

Comment: I thinked about it, but... doing this only for one situation looks a little bit overkill for me. I mean there are probably exist something more simple... I hope at least.

Comment: Also I believe having string length of 1000 for a text area in client side is fine. But not on server side, Because the plain text in the text area will be interpreted as a HTML when sent to server right? So it will always be more than what the user has entered.

Comment: you can end up in writing a plain HTML rather than `<td>@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Text)</td>` where you can specify the max length of the string directly in HTML and not having it in the server code